# Consultar N cantidad de registros en PostgreSQL en Centos 7

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, web

Al realizar una consulta de **10578** registros a través de una aplicación web, ésta tarda **2 Horas con 20 Minutos en terminar de mostrar los registros.**

El servidor utilizado es **CENTOS 7**, la base de datos indexada es PostgreSQL , y el lenguaje utilizado para mostrar la consuta es **PERL**.

Agradceré su apoyo para agilizar la consulta porque se toma demasiado tiempo.

REALICE LAS SIGUIENTES MODIFICACIONES:
**Modifique la variable Timeout 600** en el archivo **httpd.conf**
Así como los **shared_buffers= 1GB** en el archivo **postgresql.conf**

Y estaba respondiendo bien pero nuevamente muestra **GATEWAY TIMEOUT**

**RESPETOS PARA USTEDES.**

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: diez mil registros es un volumen despreciable (a menos que cada registro sea de varios MB de tamaño o algo así). Añade datos de tu problema, la consulta que haces, la estructura de las tablas, los índices involucrados, un EXPLAIN ANALYZE de la consulta pa ver qué dice la BD y todo eso, vas a recibir respuestas útiles. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Para consultar una cantidad específica de registros en una tabla en PostgreSQL en un sistema operativo Centos 7, puedes utilizar la cláusula "LIMIT" en tu consulta SQL. Por ejemplo, si deseas consultar solo los primeros 10 registros de una tabla llamada "customers", puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 10;
```

Esta consulta seleccionará todas las columnas (*) de la tabla "customers" y solo mostrará las primeras 10 filas de la tabla.

También puedes utilizar la cláusula "OFFSET" para saltear un cierto número de registros antes de comenzar a mostrar los resultados. Por ejemplo, si deseas ver los siguientes 10 registros después de los primeros 10, puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Esta consulta salteará las primeras 10 filas y mostrará las siguientes 10.

Ten en cuenta que estas consultas no eliminan los registros, solo establecen un limite de los mismos.

Espero te sirva

Comment: ¿Qué relación tiene esta respuesta con lo que pregunta OP?

Comment: GRACIAS. RESPETOS.